# How can I anchor a widget's position to a Treeview xview in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I'm trying to make an application where a user can edit the information in a TreeView widget by typing into entry boxes placed on the TreeView itself (much like you can do in the Windows File Explorer to change a file name).

I've gotten it to partially work by querying the selected item and using the `TreeView.bbox(item,column="#0")` function to get the coordinates to place an Entry widget. However, I *also* want these widgets to follow the cells around if the user scrolls the TreeView. The initial placement behavior is correct, i.e. the Entry widgets are not visible if the corresponding column is outside of the current view, and the *initial* position of the widget corresponds with the position of the corresponding cell when the widget is placed. But I can't figure out how to update the widget position when the TreeView xview or yview is changed.

Here is a simplified example of what I'm currently doing:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class TreeViewWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.xscroll = tk.Scrollbar(self,orient='horizontal')
        self.yscroll = tk.Scrollbar(self,orient='vertical')
        self.list = ttk.Treeview(self,columns=("#1","#2","#3"), 
                    selectmode='extended',xscrollcommand=self.xscroll.set,yscrollcommand=self.yscroll.set)
        self.xscroll.configure(command=self.list.xview)
        self.yscroll.configure(command=self.list.yview)

        for cc,ii in zip(self.list['columns'],range(len(self.list['columns']))):
            self.list.column(cc,minwidth=150)
            self.list.heading(cc,text=f'Column {ii}')
        self.list.column("#0",minwidth=150)
        self.list.heading("#0",text="Name")

        self.list.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='news')
        self.xscroll.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='ew')
        self.yscroll.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='ns')
        self.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.list.bind("<F2>",self.__editentry)

        self.disptext = tk.StringVar(self,value='')
        self.display = tk.Label(self,textvariable=self.disptext)
        self.display.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='ne')
        
        self.__inputvars = None
        self.__inputboxes = None
        
        # insert some items into the tree
        for i in range(10):
            self.list.insert('', 'end',iid='line%i' % i, text='line:%s' % i, values=('parent', i, 'hello'))
            for j in ('a','b'):
                self.list.insert('line%i' % i,'end',iid=f'line{i}{j}', text=f'line:{i}{j}', values = ('child',f'{j}','goodbye'))

        self.mainloop()

    def __editentry(self,event):
        iid = self.list.selection()
        if len(iid) == 0:
            return
        iid = iid[0]
        if self.__inputboxes is not None:
            self.__acceptentry()
        cols = ('#0',) + self.list['columns']
        self.__inputboxes = [None] * len(cols)
        self.__inputvars = [tk.StringVar() for ii in range(len(cols))]
        for cc,ii in zip(cols,range(len(cols))):
            bbx = self.list.bbox(iid,cc)
            if bbx == '':
                continue
            values = (self.list.item(iid,'text'),) + self.list.item(iid,'values')
            if ii == 0:
                self.__inputaccept = tk.Button(self.list,text="Y",command=self.__acceptentry)
                self.__inputcancel = tk.Button(self.list,text="N",command=self.__rejectentry)
                self.__inputaccept.place(anchor='nw',x=bbx[0],y=bbx[1])
                self.__inputaccept.update_idletasks()
                bbx = (bbx[0]+self.__inputaccept.winfo_width(),bbx[1],bbx[2]-self.__inputaccept.winfo_width(),bbx[3])
                self.__inputcancel.place(anchor='nw',x=bbx[0],y=bbx[1])
                self.__inputcancel.update_idletasks()
                bbx = (bbx[0]+self.__inputcancel.winfo_width(),bbx[1],bbx[2]-self.__inputcancel.winfo_width(),bbx[3])
            self.__inputboxes[ii] = tk.Entry(self.list,relief=tk.FLAT,textvariable=self.__inputvars[ii],bd=3,highlightthickness=1,highlightbackground='black',highlightcolor='black')
            self.__inputvars[ii].set(values[ii])
            self.__inputboxes[ii].place(anchor='nw',x=bbx[0],y=bbx[1],width=bbx[2],height=bbx[3])
            self.__inputboxes[ii].bind('<FocusIn>',lambda event: event.widget.configure(highlightthickness=2,highlightbackground='red',highlightcolor='red'))
            self.__inputboxes[ii].bind('<FocusOut>',lambda event: event.widget.configure(highlightthickness=1,highlightbackground='black',highlightcolor='black'))
        self.__acceptbind = self.bind('<Return>',self.__acceptentry)
        self.__rejectbind = self.bind('<Escape>',self.__rejectentry)
        self.__acceptid = iid

    def __acceptentry(self,event=None):
        self.unbind('<Return>',self.__acceptbind)
        self.unbind('<Escape>',self.__rejectbind)
        values = tuple(vv.get() for vv in self.__inputvars)
        for ii in range(len(self.__inputboxes)):
            self.__inputboxes[ii].destroy()
        self.__inputboxes = None
        self.__inputvars = None
        self.__inputaccept.destroy()
        self.__inputcancel.destroy()
        self.list.item(self.__acceptid,text=values[0],values=values[1:])
        self.__acceptid = None
    
    def __rejectentry(self,event=None):
        self.unbind('<Return>',self.__acceptbind)
        self.unbind('<Escape>',self.__rejectbind)
        for ii in range(len(self.__inputboxes)):
            self.__inputboxes[ii].destroy()
        self.__inputaccept.destroy()
        self.__inputcancel.destroy()
        self.__inputboxes = None
        self.__inputvars = None
        self.__acceptid = None


if __name__=="__main__":
    TreeViewWindow()
```

I'm using Python 3.8 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I figured out a somewhat hacky way to do it by interposing my own scroll handler function between the TreeView and the Scrollbars. After every scroll event, if the entry widgets have been placed on the TreeView, their positions are updated to whatever the new `TreeView.bbox(itm,column)` is after the scroll event. It seems to be a little laggy, but it does work. I'd still like to know if someone else has a better solution, though.

Working code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class TreeViewWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.xscroll = tk.Scrollbar(self,orient='horizontal',command=lambda *val, dir='x': self.__scrollhandler(*val,direction=dir))
        self.yscroll = tk.Scrollbar(self,orient='vertical',command=lambda *val, dir='y': self.__scrollhandler(*val,direction=dir))
        self.list = ttk.Treeview(self,columns=("#1","#2","#3"), 
                    selectmode='extended',
                    xscrollcommand=lambda *val, dir='x',src='list': self.__scrollhandler(*val,direction=dir,source=src),
                    yscrollcommand=lambda *val, dir='y',src='list': self.__scrollhandler(*val,direction=dir,source=src))

        for cc,ii in zip(self.list['columns'],range(len(self.list['columns']))):
            self.list.column(cc,minwidth=150)
            self.list.heading(cc,text=f'Column {ii}')
        self.list.column("#0",minwidth=150)
        self.list.heading("#0",text="Name")

        self.list.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='news')
        self.xscroll.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='ew')
        self.yscroll.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='ns')
        self.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.list.bind("<F2>",self.__editentry)

        self.disptext = tk.StringVar(self,value='')
        self.display = tk.Label(self,textvariable=self.disptext)
        self.display.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='ne')
        
        self.__inputvars = None
        self.__inputboxes = None
        self.__acceptid = None
        
        # insert some items into the tree
        for i in range(10):
            self.list.insert('', 'end',iid='line%i' % i, text='line:%s' % i, values=('parent', i, 'hello'))
            for j in ('a','b'):
                self.list.insert('line%i' % i,'end',iid=f'line{i}{j}', text=f'line:{i}{j}', values = ('child',f'{j}','goodbye'))

        self.mainloop()
    
    def __scrollhandler(self,*val,direction='y',source='scroll'):
        if source=='scroll' and direction=='x':
            self.list.xview(*val)
        elif source=='scroll' and direction=='y':
            self.list.yview(*val)
        elif source=='list' and direction=='x':
            self.xscroll.set(*val)
        elif source=='list' and direction=='y':
            self.yscroll.set(*val)
        self.list.update_idletasks()
        self.__forgetentryboxes()
        self.__placeentryboxes()
    
    def __placeentryboxes(self,iid=None):
        if iid is None:
            iid = self.__acceptid
        if iid is None:
            return
        cols = ('#0',) + self.list['columns']
        for cc,ii in zip(cols,range(len(cols))):
            bbx = self.list.bbox(iid,cc)
            if bbx == '':
                continue
            if ii == 0:
                self.__inputaccept.place(anchor='nw',x=bbx[0],y=bbx[1])
                self.__inputaccept.update_idletasks()
                bbx = (bbx[0]+self.__inputaccept.winfo_width(),bbx[1],bbx[2]-self.__inputaccept.winfo_width(),bbx[3])
                self.__inputcancel.place(anchor='nw',x=bbx[0],y=bbx[1])
                self.__inputcancel.update_idletasks()
                bbx = (bbx[0]+self.__inputcancel.winfo_width(),bbx[1],bbx[2]-self.__inputcancel.winfo_width(),bbx[3])
            self.__inputboxes[ii].place(anchor='nw',x=bbx[0],y=bbx[1],width=bbx[2],height=bbx[3])
    
    def __forgetentryboxes(self):
        if self.__inputboxes is not None:
            for bx in self.__inputboxes:
                bx.place_forget()
            self.__inputaccept.place_forget()
            self.__inputcancel.place_forget()

    def __editentry(self,event):
        iid = self.list.selection()
        if len(iid) == 0:
            return
        iid = iid[0]
        if self.__inputboxes is not None:
            self.__acceptentry()
        cols = ('#0',) + self.list['columns']
        self.__inputvars = [tk.StringVar() for ii in range(len(cols))]
        self.__inputboxes = [tk.Entry(self.list,relief=tk.FLAT,textvariable=var,bd=3,highlightthickness=1,highlightbackground='black',highlightcolor='black') for var in self.__inputvars]

        self.__inputaccept = tk.Button(self.list,text="Y",command=self.__acceptentry)
        self.__inputcancel = tk.Button(self.list,text="N",command=self.__rejectentry)
        self.__placeentryboxes(iid)
        values = (self.list.item(iid,'text'),) + self.list.item(iid,'values')
        for bx,var,val in zip(self.__inputboxes,self.__inputvars,values):
            var.set(val)
            bx.bind('<FocusIn>',lambda event: event.widget.configure(highlightthickness=2,highlightbackground='red',highlightcolor='red'))
            bx.bind('<FocusOut>',lambda event: event.widget.configure(highlightthickness=1,highlightbackground='black',highlightcolor='black'))
        self.__acceptbind = self.bind('<Return>',self.__acceptentry)
        self.__rejectbind = self.bind('<Escape>',self.__rejectentry)
        self.__acceptid = iid

    def __acceptentry(self,event=None):
        self.unbind('<Return>',self.__acceptbind)
        self.unbind('<Escape>',self.__rejectbind)
        values = tuple(vv.get() for vv in self.__inputvars)
        for ii in range(len(self.__inputboxes)):
            self.__inputboxes[ii].destroy()
        self.__inputboxes = None
        self.__inputvars = None
        self.__inputaccept.destroy()
        self.__inputcancel.destroy()
        self.list.item(self.__acceptid,text=values[0],values=values[1:])
        self.__acceptid = None
    
    def __rejectentry(self,event=None):
        self.unbind('<Return>',self.__acceptbind)
        self.unbind('<Escape>',self.__rejectbind)
        for ii in range(len(self.__inputboxes)):
            self.__inputboxes[ii].destroy()
        self.__inputaccept.destroy()
        self.__inputcancel.destroy()
        self.__inputboxes = None
        self.__inputvars = None
        self.__acceptid = None


if __name__=="__main__":
    TreeViewWindow()
```